# API request returning error code 400, when i try to decode the InputStream to Bitmap before the Retrofit enqueue

Tags: java, android, bitmap, retrofit, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to send the POST API request to the Server like below and I'm getting the successful response `code - 200`, but when I try to decode the InputStream to Bitmap, then only the API requests get failed status `code - 400`, what went wrong with this approach

```
   InputStream inputStream = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBodyUtil.create(MediaType.get("image/" + imgType), inputStream);
          
                RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("messaging_product", “help”)
                        .addFormDataPart("file", "image/" + imgType, requestBody)
                        .addFormDataPart("type", "image/" + imgType)
                        .build();
    
                //---#####if I remove the below line, then everything working fine #####
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");


                Call<ModelGraphResponse> call = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitClient().create(IService.class).uploadImageToGraph(name, body);
             
              
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelGraphResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelGraphResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ModelGraphResponse> response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                           
                        } else {
                                                           }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ModelGraphResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
                        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        textView.setText("Failed to Upload..");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Why do you try to convert an inputstream to bitmap?

Comment: And what is it that you want to do with the bitmap?

Comment: And how does your imgUri look like.?

Comment: Which 'request'  is is in your POST request?

Comment: Thank you for your question, there are my answers, I want to convert to byte[] and store them in the sqllite databse,

Comment: You have put the `InputStream` in the request body. Then you try to read the `InputStream` to Bitmap. This will make the `InputStream` invalid so on your next step sending the API will be failed.

Comment: So I guess @blackapps is asking why you start to decode your input stream in to bitmap in the middle of your API call. If you decides to use `InputStream` to do many tasks (e.g., API call first, then have a glance on the stream and at least save it to DB), you shall retain a deep copy of it for every single tasks.

Comment: So I believe you are asking "How do I deep clone an InputStream without consuming it"

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
URL url = new URL(//your URL//);
 try { 
HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//YOUR CODE

Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, what is the URL here, Base Url ?

Comment: your Image URL @Prasath